# Is sfdx force:source:deploy a transactional command? Could it be?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, transaction

I'm looking for a transactional deployment command, that will roll back the entire metadata movement in case of an error.

Deploying by using an artifact with `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --zipfile ...` is a solution proposed by Salesforce in [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/org-development-model/test-and-deploy-changes?trail_id=determine-which-application-lifecycle-management-model-is-right-for-you&trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=architect-dev-lifecycle-and-deployment), which makes the case. However, it requires the previous creation of an artifact.

Instead, I want to use `sfdx force:source:deploy`, but that previous trailhead module indicates that `sfdx force:source:deploy` is not transactional and only for local and development purposes, which is opposite to what is mentioned in the following article ["Release your app to Production"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_mdapi_production.htm?_ga=2.66862508.367748850.1667206463-259957257.1664783855) or [this post by Ivan Harris](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S000008JQCVSA4).

Is `source:deploy` actually a transactional command? Besides that, any feedback about what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you can deploy code using this command that breaks other code that has dependencies on that code (eg, changing a method name), but not in production orgs. You can avoid this by deploying your entire code base every time, optionally with unit test runs. This is the same behavior as the original metadata API.

The trailhead module is outdated. You can indeed deploy to production environments now. It is fully transactional for production environments, as all code is complied on deployment, even code not included in the deployment. For all other environments, compilation only occurs for included components. You can use the -o and -g parameters to allow partial rollback in those environments.